# How to create a tipping function in python

Tags: python

trying to fix this code for tipping.
Let's add a tipping function. I've created the bare-bones of the function, which will take in the cost of the meal, and ask for a percentage to tip on the meal. You do the rest!

```
def tip(cost):
percentage = input("What percent would you like to tip? ")
tip = round(cost * percentage, 2)
print("The tip amount of", percentage, "% is ", tip)
return tip
```

the first part does not seem to work

after that, I run

```
cost, items = order(menu)
print("Your order is", items)
cost = round(cost + tax("vt", cost, tax_rate), 2)
cost = round(cost + tip(cost), 2)
print("Your total cost is", cost)
```

Comment: The percentage needs to be converted from a string to a number (float) in the tip function.

Comment: please indent the code inside the function

Comment: _the first part does not seem to work_ This doesn't tell us much.  Please say what the code actually does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert the input to float in order to perform mathmatical operation . Otherwise it will multiply the string with number and return a repeated string.

```
def tip(cost):
    percentage = float(input("What percent would you like to tip? "))
    tip = round(cost * percentage, 2)
    print("The tip amount of", percentage, "% is ", tip)
    return tip
```

Comment: What item is being ordered? [ Press enter to total ]fries
you chose: fries
Your order: ['fries']
Current Subtotal: 0.36
What item is being ordered? [ Press enter to total ]
you chose: 
Your order is ['fries']
Taxes are 0.03
What percent would you like to tip? 5
The tip amount of 5.0 % is  1.95
Your total cost is 2.34

Comment: I am getting 1.95 as 5% of .39, should it not be .0195 have I forgotten a step.

Comment: The problem is you are rounding the no. Which maybe increasing your percentage.

Comment: I figured it out I took the tip = cost * percentage and / by 100 and it works right now thanks for the help above.